# Sending push notification to iPhone via AppleScript

Tags: iphone, applescript, apns

Is there any combination of iPhone and/or Mac apps that I can use to send a push notification to my iPhone?

For example, let's say I want to create a service (invoked via (Application Name) > Services) which sends the highlighted text on my Mac to my iPhone as a push notification message.

Answer (score 7):

I think a combination of [**Growl**](http://growl.info/) (OS X notifier) and [**Prowl**](http://www.prowlapp.com/) (an iPhone app that forwards Push Notifcations from Growl) with your AppleScript interacting with Growl directly would be the way to go for this.

Answer (score 4):

The free app [Boxcar](http://boxcar.io/) allows you to forward Growl notifications to your iPhone. You can also use their [API](http://boxcar.io/help/api/providers) to send custom push notifications from any app or script. I use it with Growl (never used their API, though) and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

1. Register at [Prowl](http://www.prowlapp.com/)
2. Install the Prowl iOS app on your iPhone
3. Use this script in OSX ('sendClipboardAsPush.sh') to send your clipboard to your iPhone as push notification:

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> set -x
> # Posts growl notifications to iOS device using prowl & curl
>
> # Fill in with your own Prowl API key here and remove 123456789
> APIKEY=123456789
> # Make up a cache filename in /tmp/ based on our PID
> CACHE=/tmp/$$.cache.txt
>
> # clipboard -> temp file CACHE
> pbpaste > $CACHE
>
> # Post notification to Prowl using curl
> curl --globoff https://api.prowlapp.com/publicapi/add \
>   -F apikey=$APIKEY \
>   -F application=RSS \
>   -F event="" \
>   -F description="`cat $CACHE`"
>
> rm $CACHE
> ```

You can find your [Prowl API key here](https://www.prowlapp.com/api_settings.php).

Answer (score 1):

I have recently [written an applescript](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=41045) to send boxcar notifications. It would be accessed via a Terminal command:

`osascript /path/to/script boxcar_username "Title of Notification" "Body of Notification" "URL/to/54x54icon"`

This in turn maps to:

`on run {BoxcarUSER, boxcartitle, boxcarmessage, BoxcarICONURL}`

The BoxcarUSER variable is the only required one, the rest will use defaults.
If you have your own provider, you can open the script in script editor and change the property at the top of the script(I currently have it setuo with a provider I created, so feel free to change that)
Other defaults could be changed within the  `set {` in the `run{}` handler.
Some of the error catching is rough, as if you do not have an internet connection, cURL will fail with a non zero status (I think, no real expert there) so the script can't catch the error message.

Some ideas I have thought about.
Since you can map the icon that shows in boxcar, you could use different 57x57 icons to show the user different things that are happening. So maybe you could push out a red icon for stop, green for go, etc.

```
--Usage on the command line would be:
--osascript path/to/script "Email-Address" "Title of Notification" "Message of Notification" "http://address_of_57x57_image"
--All these fields are optional but fields that want to use defaults should use ""

property AS2BoxcarVersion : "0.8.2"


(*
Versions:
0.8.2
Cleaned up code, made it more readable
Added "date" option to insert date into notification, so now boxcartitle or boxcarmessage can be "date" and this would return (current date)
0.8.1
Script now returns message when successful
0.8
Made all fields optional, expect for BoxcarUSER, and BoxcarDefaultAPIKey.  These 2 are required for the script to function
0.7
Made the icon Boxcar shows passable in terminal, see second line of script for syntax
0.6:
Added Support if boxcar API service is down
0.5:
Initial Release, works as expected, just no features

*)

--on run {}
--  my test123("identd@me.com", "date", "date", "")
--end run

on run {BoxcarUSER, boxcartitle, boxcarmessage, BoxcarICONURL}
    
    
    --reset variables, this is where you can set your defaults, remember these should all be strings!
    set {BoxcarDefaultTitle, BoxcarDefaultMessage, BoxcarDefaultICON, BoxcarDefaultAPIKey} to {"Boxcar Version: " & AS2BoxcarVersion, "Yup, This all looks good!", "http://i39.tinypic.com/b85nd4.jpg", "BHyitk1NJ37xRLKg6rnQ"}
    --end reset
    --  display dialog boxcartitle as string
    if boxcartitle is "" then
        set boxcartitle to BoxcarDefaultTitle
    else if boxcartitle is "date" then
        set boxcartitle to ((current date) as text)
    end if
    --  display dialog boxcartitle as string
    if boxcarmessage is "" then
        set boxcarmessage to BoxcarDefaultMessage
    else if boxcarmessage is "date" then
        set boxcarmessage to ((current date) as text)
    end if
    if BoxcarICONURL is "" then
        set BoxcarICONURL to BoxcarDefaultICON
    end if
    
    set SubscribeServiceResponse to (do shell script "curl -d \"email=" & BoxcarUSER & "\" \\
[url=http://boxcar.io/devices/providers/]http://boxcar.io/devices/providers/"[/url] & BoxcarDefaultAPIKey & "/notifications/subscribe")
    
    delay 1
    
    set boxcartitle to ListToString(stringtolist(boxcartitle, " "), "+")
    set boxcarmessage to ListToString(stringtolist(boxcarmessage, " "), "+")
    
    try
        set BoxcarResponse to (do shell script "curl -d \"emails=" & BoxcarUSER & "\" \\
-d \"&notification[from_screen_name]=" & boxcartitle & "\" \\
-d \"&notification[message]=" & boxcarmessage & "\" \\
-d \"&notification[icon_url]=" & BoxcarICONURL & "\" \\
-d \"&notification[from_remote_service_id]=" & my md5create(((current date) & BoxcarUSER & BoxcarDefaultTitle & BoxcarDefaultMessage as text)) & "\" \\
[url=http://boxcar.io/devices/providers/]http://boxcar.io/devices/providers/"[/url] & BoxcarDefaultAPIKey & "/notifications")
        if BoxcarResponse contains "favicon.ico" then
            return ("AS2Boxcar v" & AS2BoxcarVersion & ": Boxcar API Service is temporarily down. Error 1")
        end if
        if BoxcarResponse contains "Could not resolve host" then
            return ("AS2Boxcar v" & AS2BoxcarVersion & ": Unable to resolve http://boxcar.io  Please check your internet connection.")
        end if
    on error errmsg
        return ("AS2Boxcar v" & AS2BoxcarVersion & ": Boxcar API Service is temporarily down. Error 2")
    end try
    --return ("AS2Boxcar " & AS2BoxcarVersion & ": Notification sent to " & BoxcarUSER)
    return ("AS2Boxcar " & AS2BoxcarVersion & ": " & BoxcarUSER & " : " & boxcartitle & " : " & boxcarmessage & " : " & BoxcarICONURL)
end run

--SUBS--
on stringtolist(theString, delim)
    set oldelim to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to delim
    set dlist to (every text item of theString)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldelim
    return dlist
end stringtolist

on ListToString(theList, delim)
    set oldelim to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to delim
    set alist to theList as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldelim
    return alist
end ListToString

on md5create(stringtohash)
    set hashedBoxcarUSER to item 2 of stringtolist((do shell script "md5 -s \"" & stringtohash & "\""), " = ")
    return hashedBoxcarUSER
end md5create
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're looking for, but you could use [Find my iPhone](http://me.com/find). It's [free](http://lifehacker.com/#!5696311/how-to-enable-and-use-find-my-iphone-for-free-on-iphone-3gs-and-other-pre+2010-devices), native and [easy to install](http://www.apple.com/iphone/find-my-iphone-setup/) and it [features](http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/find-my-iphone.html) a "Display Message" that's pushed into the phone.

Comment: Is there an API for "Display Message"? That would be necessary, in some form, for calling in AppleScript.

Comment: @Timothy I really don't know, but I'd bet there isn't.

Comment: So Find My iPhone is somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: @Timothy true, but it's close enough to worth mentioning. It could even be used as a solution if it's for low usage.

Comment: True. I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

There is a web service http://pushme.to/ and ios app that could be implemented that would solve your problem although it doesn't appear to be in the app store at the moment pending some bug fixes i believe.

There are other apps that use an api to push messages to an ios device via a wordpress site oddly. http://ipush.me/

you should be able to create a native app using a website (you could create) that effectively is a form to send the details (name/message) to this service.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else stumbles upon this, just wanted to update and recommend https://boxcar.io/ as a solution.

Right now I'm using it to send a notification to myself when my Macbook
s battery is running low. For this I just created a PHP script and added it to my crontab.

Basic script is:

```
<?php
$notify_when_below = 10;
$battery_charge = trim(exec("pmset -g batt | grep -o ...% | grep -o ..."));
if((int)$battery_charge < $notify_when_below){
    curl_setopt_array(
    $chpush = curl_init(),
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://new.boxcar.io/api/notifications",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        "user_credentials" => 'YOUR_DEVICE_ACCESS_TOKEN',
        "notification[title]" => 'Low battery alert!',
        "notification[long_message]" => '<b>Macbook battery level is at '.(int)$battery_charge.'%!</b>',
        "notification[sound]" => "detonator-charge",
    )));
    $ret = curl_exec($chpush);
    curl_close($chpush);
}
```