# Send Mac Notification to iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

The Basic Question: 
I'd like to send notifications from my Mac desktop to my phone. I'm familiar with Growl and Prowl, but neither of those projects has been updated in years (understandably at this stage) and all the threads I'm finding ([this one for example)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8906/sending-push-notification-to-iphone-via-applescript) are from several years ago as well. Has there been any developments in this area, or is this still really the only way to go to get desktop notifications to iOS?

Non-Essential Details: 
I got a Martian Notifier watch for Christmas, which gives my wrist a buzz any time I get a notification on my phone. This has drastically cut down on "Oh crap, my wife texted me like an hour ago!" moments and so I'd like to be able to do the same thing with Adium chats at work. I'm assuming the best way to do this is to push the notification to my phone, but I'm definitely open to other solutions as well.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but have you looked into iOS clients that support whatever chat service you are using Adium with? For example: [IM+](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/im+-instant-messenger/id285688934?mt=8) That's assuming that you are using something like GChat/Google Hangouts with Google Apps for work chat. If it's a self-hosted solution, my question is irrelevant :)

Comment: I did actually consider just using the native apps for each chat service but a problem I run into there is that since I don't actually use the phone apps all that often, I find they eventually log themselves out for whatever reason (app updates most likely). So eventually the notifications will just stop until I realize I haven't gotten a notification in some time and log back in. Also, non-persistent services like MS Lync will sometimes only send the message to one client, so if it does go to the phone, I won't get it at my desk. Thanks for trying though.