# How do I receive iOS app notifications on my Mac?

Tags: ios, catalina, notifications

I would like to mirror all notifications (including third-party apps) from my iPhone (5s with iOS 12) on my Macbook Air 2017 (Catalina 10.15).

My phone is not jailbreaked. Is there a native way to achieve it nethertheless?

Comment: I might be possible but we'd need to know more info on your devices.  What OS versions?  What have you tried already?  What problem are you trying to solve?  See [ask] for more info. - From Review

Comment: There's no way to do this natively, but there may be some Applescript and/or 3rd party solutions to this:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/8906/119271

Comment: That link is very dated. i wonder if it's contents even apply today...

Answer (score 1):

A recent app to do what you want is [Notifyr](http://www.getnotifyr.com) This app will supposedly send all Notifications to you Mac.  You need a mac built 2012 or later. This does vary for different computers and the actual years are given in the link.

Comment: This is not working for me on a Macbook Air from 2017 that has Bluetooth 4. I am getting the error that it cannot find Bluetooth 4 on my device.

Comment: Have you contacted the developers?  Sorry about that.

Comment: The developer told me that the app is no longer maintained and got removed from the store.

Comment: Probably doesn't work on newer macs.